# wso2 Business Process server 3.5.1 integration with WSO2 API manager 1.10.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Application creation workflow - Approval task is not showing in API Manager admin-dashboard after creating a new Application. [Tried with different users]

When I am checking in Business Process Server Management Console --> Human Tasks, It shows the list of Claimable talks. When I select from the list of Claimable tasks, it show the following error.

> Task request information cannot be loaded. Please check
>   ApproveApplication-input.jsp file available inside Human Task package
>   web directory.

Could you please suggest, how could I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the below step as instructed under [Configuring the API Manager](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Adding+an+Application+Registration+Workflow) heading.

Open the <`APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/admin-dashboard/site/conf/site.json` file and configure `workFlowServerURL` under `workflows` to point to the BPS server (e.g. `"workFlowServerURL": "https://localhost:9445/services/"`)